# How can we split a sentence

Tags: php

I have written the PHP code for getting some part of a given dynamic sentence, e.g. `"this is a test sentence"`:

```
substr($sentence,0,12);
```

I get the output:

```
this is a te
```

But i need it stop as a full word instead of splitting a word:

```
this is a
```

How can I do that, remembering that `$sentence` isn't a fixed string (it could be anything)?

Comment: So, just to be clear, how are you deciding how many characters to include? And is the idea that, if you end up with a partial word at the end, you'll remove the partial word (instead of completing it)? What if the first word is very long - is it OK to end up with an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

use [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap)

Comment: Specifically, `$lines = wordwrap($sentence, 12); $firstLine = $lines[0];`

Comment: @Michael - wordwrap does not return an array.

Comment: @RabidFire Wow, you're right; I swore it did. I guess `$firstLine = strstr(wordwrap($sentence, 12), "\n", true);` is easiest then, although the third `strstr` argument is relatively new (5.3.0)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP4, you can simply use `split`:

```
$resultArray = split($sentence, " ");
```

Every element of the array will be one word. Be careful with punctuation though.

`explode` would be the recommended method in PHP5:

```
$resultArray = explode(" ", $sentence);
```

Answer (score 2):

first. use explode on space. Then, count each part + the total assembled string and if it doesn't go over the limit you concat it onto the string with a space.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

In your case:

```
$expl = explode(" ",$sentence);
```

You'll get your sentence in an array. First word will be $expl[0], second - $expl[1] and so on. To print it out on the screen use:

```
$n = 10 //words to print
for ($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++) {
  print $expl[$i]." ";
}
```

Comment: @Linto P D  --  I used to do exactly as the code above. This will solve your problem. good answer. @Tom

Answer (score 0):

this is just psudo code not php,

```
char[] sentence="your_sentence";
string new_constructed_sentence="";
string word="";
for(i=0;i<your_limit;i++){
character=sentence[i];
if(character==' ') {new_constructed_sentence+=word;word="";continue}
word+=character;
}
```

new_constructed_sentence is what you want!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that you can re-use at any time. This will look for the last space if the given string's length is greater than the amount of characters you want to trim.

```
function niceTrim($str, $trimLen) {
    $strLen = strlen($str);
    if ($strLen > $trimLen) {
        $trimStr = substr($str, 0, $trimLen);
        return substr($trimStr, 0, strrpos($trimStr, ' '));
    }
    return $str;
}

$sentence = "this is a test sentence";
echo niceTrim($sentence, 12);
```

This will print

```
this is a
```

as required.

Hope this is the solution you are looking for!